# GDAL cannot read KML file that it just created

Tags: gdal, kml, c, swift

I'm using GDAL 2.2 standard C library within a Swift wrapper in an iOS app.  After creating a KML data source and populating it with data, GDAL is unable to open the KML file that it just created.  QGIS can open it just fine.

I create the file like this:

```swift
gdalDriver = GDALGetDriverByName("KML".cString(using: .utf8)) else {
    print("FAILED to get driver by name '\(driverName)")
    return nil
}

guard let ogrDS = GDALCreate(gdalDriver, url.path.cString(using: .utf8), 0, 0, 0, GDT_Unknown, nil) else { return nil }
```

This all works fine, and the file is created, I then populate it with features.  QGIS can open the KML file.  Then I try to open it with GDAL like this:

```swift
        let path = url.path
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            print("File for DS does not exist:  \(url.lastPathComponent)")
            return nil
        }
        
        var ogrDS = GDALOpenEx(path.cString(using: .utf8), UInt32(GDAL_OF_VECTOR|GDAL_OF_UPDATE|GDAL_OF_VERBOSE_ERROR), nil, nil, nil)
        if ogrDS == nil {
            ogrDS = GDALOpenEx(path.cString(using: .utf8), UInt32(GDAL_OF_VECTOR|GDAL_OF_READONLY|GDAL_OF_VERBOSE_ERROR), nil, nil, nil)
            if ogrDS == nil {
                let err = String.init(cString: CPLGetLastErrorMsg())
                print("FAILED to open existing datasource:  \(url.path)\nERROR:  \(err)")
                return nil
            } else {
                print("WARNING:  Read-only datasource:  \(url.lastPathComponent)")
            }
        }
```

However, this fails with the error:

> ERROR 4: `/Users/blahblahblah/Documents/Waypoints.kml' not recognized as a supported file format.

How can I get GDAL to open the KML file that it just created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that GDAL's KML driver will write KML just fine, but will not read KML unless it has been compiled with the Expat library.

I only figured this out because I was having a similar problem with GPX, but at least the error GDAL gave for GPX clearly stated that it cannot read GPX without the Expat library.  The error for KML was much less helpful!

After thinking about it, I realised that GPX and KML are both XML extensions, and that's what Expat is all about.  So I then checked the GDAL KML driver page more carefully, and noticed the requirement listed there.

UPDATE:  Confirmed.  I got around to rebuilding GDAL with Expat, and now I can read KML (and GPX).

Comment: I'm running into this exact issue using the C++ API. I make a KML file, add some features, close it, and then I'm not able to open again with the GDAL_OF_UPDATE flag. Opening with with GDAL_OF_VECTOR only (ie: read only) is possible though. However I HAVE built GDAL with EXPAT and still have no luck. I'll post back here if I work it out. In your post you said "now I can read KML" - were you able to open and file and edit/write as well?